# How to retrieve the native font name in Java?

Tags: java, fonts

Is there a way in Java to get the native font name from a `Font` object?

I get my Font using this code `Font.decode("Serif")` and for debugging purpose I would like to know the native font used.

Comment: What do you mean by "native font"?

Comment: There _is_ the way since there are Java applications which show you native fonts installed on the system (e.g., IntelliJ IDEA shows list of fonts like `DejaVu Sans Mono` on my Linux box). It's just that I don't exact steps to achieve this :)

Comment: Have you tried font.getFontName() ?

Comment: @TylerDurden By native font I mean Physical font like "Times New Roman", "Arial"... Serif is the name of the one of the Logical font defined in Java, and Java mapped these Logical fonts to physical fonts.

Comment: BTW, getFontName gives me "Serif" for the logical font Serif, but gives me "Times-Roman" for the logical font Times. I didn't research any further, but I'm guessing that those are the 'native' font names (I'm on OS X).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It might not be that simple.  Some fonts are composed of many physical fonts, using different physical fonts for different glyphs.

For example, on my Windows system the Serif font uses 12 physical fonts:

- ** TrueType Font: Family=Times New Roman Name=Times New Roman style=0 fileName=C:\Windows\Fonts\TIMES.TTF
- ** TrueType Font: Family=Wingdings Name=Wingdings style=0 fileName=C:\Windows\Fonts\WINGDING.TTF
- ** TrueType Font: Family=Symbol Name=Symbol style=0 fileName=C:\Windows\Fonts\SYMBOL.TTF
- ** TrueType Font: Family=Lucida Sans Name=Lucida Sans Regular style=0 fileName=C:\Java\jdk\jdk1.6.0_37\jre\lib\fonts\LucidaSansRegular.ttf
- ** TrueType Font: Family=MingLiU Name=MingLiU style=0 fileName=C:\Windows\Fonts\MINGLIU.TTC
- ** TrueType Font: Family=Lucida Sans Name=Lucida Sans Regular style=0 fileName=C:\Java\jdk\jdk1.6.0_37\jre\lib\fonts\LucidaSansRegular.ttf
- ** TrueType Font: Family=SimSun Name=SimSun style=0 fileName=C:\Windows\Fonts\SIMSUN.TTC
- ** TrueType Font: Family=Lucida Sans Name=Lucida Sans Regular style=0 fileName=C:\Java\jdk\jdk1.6.0_37\jre\lib\fonts\LucidaSansRegular.ttf
- ** TrueType Font: Family=MS Mincho Name=MS Mincho style=0 fileName=C:\Windows\Fonts\MSMINCHO.TTC
- ** TrueType Font: Family=Batang Name=Batang style=0 fileName=C:\Windows\Fonts\batang.TTC
- ** TrueType Font: Family=MingLiU-ExtB Name=MingLiU-ExtB style=0 fileName=C:\Windows\Fonts\MINGLIUB.TTC
- ** TrueType Font: Family=SimSun-ExtB Name=SimSun-ExtB style=0 fileName=C:\Windows\Fonts\SIMSUNB.TTF

The following code can break down a font into its physical components.  It uses a reflection hack to access a `sun.awt.Font2D` object, so use at your own risk (works with Oracle Java 6u37):

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Locale;

import sun.font.CompositeFont;
import sun.font.Font2D;
import sun.font.PhysicalFont;

public class FontTester
{
    public static void main(String... args)
    throws Exception
    {
        Font font = new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 12);
        describeFont(font);
    }

    private static void describeFont(Font font)
    throws Exception
    {
        Method method = font.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getFont2D");
        method.setAccessible(true);
        Font2D f = (Font2D)method.invoke(font);

        describeFont2D(f);
    }

    private static void describeFont2D(Font2D font)
    {
        if (font instanceof CompositeFont)
        {
            System.out.println("Font '" + font.getFontName(Locale.getDefault()) + "' is composed of:");

            CompositeFont cf = (CompositeFont)font;
            for (int i = 0; i < cf.getNumSlots(); i++)
            {
                PhysicalFont pf = cf.getSlotFont(i);
                describeFont2D(pf);
            }
        }
        else
            System.out.println("-> " + font);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[prunge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/523391/prunge)'s answer was nearly perfect, except that it didn't actually expose the native (physical) font's name.  The following tiny change to the describeFont2D method does the trick by again leveraging Java reflection:

Don't forget to import java.lang.reflect.Field;

```
private static void describeFont2D( Font2D font ) throws Exception{
    if( font instanceof CompositeFont ){
        System.out.println( "Font '"+font.getFontName( Locale.getDefault() )+"' is composed of:" );
        CompositeFont cf = ( CompositeFont )font;
        for( int i = 0; i<cf.getNumSlots(); i++ ){
            PhysicalFont pf = cf.getSlotFont( i );
            describeFont2D( pf );
        }
    }else if( font instanceof CFont ){
        Field field = CFont.class.getDeclaredField( "nativeFontName" );
        field.setAccessible( true );
        String nativeFontName = ( String )field.get( font );                
        System.out.println( "-> "+nativeFontName );
    }else
        System.out.println( "-> "+font );
}
```

Comment: [@dan-borque](https://stackoverflow.com/users/77479/dan-bourque), we'll also need to import `sun.font.CFont`. That said, `sun.font.CFont` is available only for Mac OS X, which limits the use of this modified method to that platform.

Answer (score 1):

This code will get the system fonts if they are available, and will get default families if for some reason they are not available:

```
static String[] AS_System_Fonts = null;
public static String[] getFontFamilies(){
    if( AS_System_Fonts != null ) return AS_System_Fonts;
    java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment gEnv = java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    AS_System_Fonts = gEnv.getAvailableFontFamilyNames();
    if( AS_System_Fonts == null ){ // should not happen
        AS_System_Fonts = new String[8];
        AS_System_Fonts[0] = "Serif";
        AS_System_Fonts[1] = "Sans-Serif";
        AS_System_Fonts[2] = "Monospaced";
        AS_System_Fonts[3] = "Dialog";
        AS_System_Fonts[4] = "Dialog Input";
        AS_System_Fonts[5] = "Lucida Bright";
        AS_System_Fonts[6] = "Lucida Sans";
        AS_System_Fonts[7] = "Lucida Sans Typewriter";
    }
    return AS_System_Fonts;
}
```

Comment: other than the non-standard variable naming (AS_System_Fonts would be much better named systemFonts), good answer!

Comment: sorry about the variable names, its an artifact of coming out of a utility kit that has specialized naming conventions, feel free to rename